# MySQL One to Many Select

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I have a one to many relationship between Table A (The one table) and Table B (The many table).

I want to query Table A and only return entries from Table A where it has at least one row in Table B.

I thought it might be an Inner Join but I am still getting a row returned for each entry in Table B.

```
SELECT * FROM categories.* INNER JOIN images ON images.category_id = categories.id
```

That is my current query, I assume it is a `WHERE` clause I need to add but I do not know what.

I apologise that this is such a simple question I couldn't find the answer myself I assume I am wording it wrong.

Comment: Please provide table structure.

Comment: You can also use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to provide full example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the categories data (not images data) with at least one association in table b you can do something like below

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN images i ON i.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) > 0
```

Or without aggregation just distinct and join

```
SELECT DISTINCT  c.* 
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN images i ON i.category_id = c.id
```

Comment: I think having clause is not need. The answer is right

Comment: GROUP BY i.category_id

Comment: Just used because of group by, group without aggregate function is not a good practice

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838285/mysql-join-sum-from-left-table

Answer (score 1):

You can do in several ways.
One could be following. It use EXISTS in WHERE condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM images WHERE images.category_id = categories.id)
```

Another can be using DISTINCT in a subquery (but I think performances are worst than former):

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT category_id FROM images) images ON images.category_id = categories.id)
```

Comment: This would have worked but instead I am going to do as @kenfire suggested, thanks heaps though!

Comment: @OliverGiess  It seems to me they could not return the same records: with RIGHT JOIN you do another thing.

Comment: I do see what you mean, I was hasty

Answer (score 1):

You can use left/right join.

```
SELECT * FROM categories.* I
RIGHT JOIN images 
ON images.category_id = categories.id
```

In you case I supposed that Table A was categories and Table B images.
Try using Left join if it's the opposite

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Good  idea to reverse the tables and simply select that way I should have thought of that myself *face palm*

Comment: @OliverGiess Some time you don't need to over think it

Answer (score 1):

Use This query

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN images i ON i.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY i.category_id
```

Comment: You cheater :).

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid hahaha what happend bro. I really appreciate your mysql knowledge