# MySQL Join Sum from Left Table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my Query

```
select 
cs.cont_selling_id,
price,
paid
from cont_selling cs
left join(
          select sum(price) as price
                ,cont_selling_id 
          from cont_sold
          group by cont_selling_id
          )x on x.cont_selling_id = cs.cont_selling_id,
left join(
          select sum(paid) as paid
                ,cont_selling_id 
          from payment
          group by cont_selling_id
          )y
on y.cont_selling_id = cs.cont_selling_id;
```

Everything works fine, but I think it will take more time as compare to normal left join because subquery works on the whole table. If cont_sold table has more than 100 000 records it will slow down the server.

My question is there any optimized way to write this query? Can we add where condition in subquery from the main table? I have seen many answers on StackOverflow but not getting any perfect answer.

Comment: Please provide [complete information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) of what are you trying to achieve

Comment: If you are using this query in `Stored Procedure` then you can first store `LEFT JOIN` data in `temporary table` then `JOIN` with the main table it will minimize the repeated whole table scan process.